# JFlex license for old Joomla site

Tags: joomla, php-5.2, jflex

i moved an 10 years old joomla site on a local php 5.2 server to rescue
some of the content.

If i run the site, the only content it shows is:
"JFlex Images FULL was not licensed for this domain."

Is there any way to safe remove these extension or change the license to a demo version?

On there site i can't find any information to resolve my problem (http://www.jflex.de/copying.html)

I hope somone can help.

Comment: "JFlex images" has nothing to do with jflex.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to **Phpmyadmin** you can unpublish this component or plugin. Log into phpmyadmin and open your **joomla 1.5 database**. Search for the string `jflex` in `jos_components` and `jos_plugins`. You will find some tables with `jflex`. Edit those rows by making published to `0`. It will get unpublished. After that you are free to log into your joomla administration.

Comment: Hey, didn't found it in jos_components or jos_plugins but in **jos_mambots**, atleast i can acces the site now. Thanks for your help!